# Cached write for memory mapped file (MappedByteBuffer)

Tags: java, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I have written a simple flat hashtable (byte[] based) using a MappedByteBuffer. However, I experienced that it is much faster if I build the hashtable in memory and then just write the byte[]-array to the MappedByteBuffer.

Hence, it looks like performance sucks for random writes since the OS is flushing quite often and a page gets modified many times. Is there a way to defer flushing of pages?

foobar

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) for the underlying mapping mechanism:

> The rate at which changes to the buffer are propagated to the file is unspecified.

So, unfortunately, no.